# Use dynamic reactive form (fields in while)

Tags: angular, formarray

I try to use reactive form with angular for build a form with all fields required.

Actually i have this code and result
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mciraa

You can see in the first section the 5 fields available.

But you can see my problem in this picture

[image]

I'm not except this result
but this one:

Title block 1 = Fields of this block (fields 1, 2 ,3)
Title block 2 = Fields of this block (fields 4, 5 and not fields 1,2)

Can you help me please?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="routerForm" class="LG_global-form" *ngIf="routerForm">
    <div class="LG_global-container" *ngFor="let bloc of sendRouterInfo; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div class="LG_global-wrap">
        <h2 class="LG_global-title">{{bloc['title']}}</h2>
        <p class="LG_intro">
          {{bloc['comment']}}
        </p>
        <div class="LG_form-line" *ngFor="let field of bloc['fields']; let i = index"  [formGroupName]="i">
          <div>Array index: {{i}}</div>
          <input formControlName="name" type="text"  />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

TS

```
this.dataFromAPi.block.forEach((bloc, index) => {
        const formArray = new FormArray([]);

        bloc.fields.forEach(field => {
          field.value = '';
          formArray.push(
              this.formBuilder.group({
                'name': [field ? field.name : ''],
                'value': [field ? field.value: '', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
              })
          );
        });
        this.routerForm.controls[index] = formArray;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you its work great but now i have a weird validation comportement.
My probleme is the valid property of the formgroup.
this property stay to valid even if the the form array is not valid how it is possible?.
[image]

Again thanks you for your help